# Add event into the same event

Tags: jquery, events, click

Sorry for the title, I don't know how to explain..

Is this possible ? :

```
$('div').click(function(){
        //code 1
        $('div2').click(function(){
           //code 2
        });
    });
```

Comment: Common handler for both, `$('div, .div2').click(function() {`?

Comment: *"I don't know how to explain"* Well, ***try***. Do you want to *hook up* a handler from with another? *Trigger* a handler from within another? Something else entirely?

Comment: Hmm, In my example, The ('div').click() function will be complete when the ('div2') is clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id1').click(function () {
    alert('div 1');
    $('#id2').click();
});
$('#id2').click(function () {
    alert('div 2');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8fnu21r/)

Manually click the div 2 inside the click event of div 1

Comment: The "#id2" trigger will be execute after the "#id1" is done or at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

This way it may be.

HTML

```
<div id="div1">Here Div1</div>
<div id="div2">Here Div2</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
var isClick = false;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div1').click(function(){
      isClick = true;
    });
    $('#div2').click(function(){
       if(isClick) {
         alert("div2 click");
       }
    });
</script>
```